# Having trouble with Bootstrap sticky header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, sticky

I'm using Bootstrap to create my animation portfolio and currently have my sticky header working, but don't know how to fix two issues with it. You can see a working example [[here]](http://jessejaymesjones.com/NEW_VERSION/index_v05.html).

- Center the header exactly above the content div (right now it has a small offset to it)
- Scale header to always take up 10% of the browser vertical size
- (optional) Would like the content div to start exactly where the header stops so nothing gets cut off

Here is what my code looks like:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="affix affix-top header-resize" style="position: top; margin: 0 auto; clear: left; height: auto; z-index: 5; text-align: center; background-size: cover; background-color: clear;">
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('img/header-bg.png'); background-size: cover; height: auto;">
<img src="img/logo.png" class="col-xs-8" alt="Jesse J. Jones - Animator/Illustrator/Designer">
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('img/header-gradient.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-size: cover; height: 20%;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-resize {
  height: 10%;
}
```

Thank you for your help! I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and responsive design, so all this is purely me experimenting and following tutorials. Let me know if I need to explain anything further! :)

Thank you,

Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add bootstrap's own ROW div. This will re-center your header:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="affix affix-top header-resize" style="position: top; margin: 0 auto; clear: left; height: auto; z-index: 5; text-align: center; background-size: cover; background-color: clear;">
            <div class="container" style="background-image: url('img/header-bg.png'); background-size: cover; height: auto;">
              <img src="img/logo.png" class="col-xs-8" alt="Jesse J. Jones - Animator/Illustrator/Designer">
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="background-image: url('img/header-gradient.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-size: cover; height: 20%;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still looking for how to keep header height always at 10% browser height if anyone knows how. Thanks!

Comment: Again, you want to use bootstrap's own syntax for your image and add these column classes: '<img class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" src="img/logo.png" alt="Jesse J. Jones - Animator/Illustrator/Designer" />'

Comment: I suggest you go and read [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to help you further ;)